# Is it beneficial to continue working for a professor, when I don't like the work, only for a letter of recommendation?

Tags: recommendation-letter, research, graduate

I am working as a research fellow to a professor in a college. This is my first time as a research fellow. I was working as a software engineer before this. I want to apply for grad schools, and to gain research experience I decided to work for this professor.

The professor has his own startup that is in very early stage. He already has a product that he is trying to sell. I don't really like the work with the professor that much. It has been two months and I worked mostly on operations work for his startup (like converting the monolith server to microservices..) and not much research.

Even the research work is not interesting because we are not trying to solve a problem but just trying to get a good accuracy score (trying to hack the existing solution here and there to get a better score), that will help to publish a paper. As I am planning to apply to graduate schools, I have to start application by this October. So I don't think I will able to do anything substantial in the mean time.

Until now I was a staff in the same college where he is a professor and was designated as a research fellow. Now I want to work remotely because of my health condition and the college is not okay with it. So I have to quit working for the college and work for him alone remotely. The college is paying me, but if quit working for the college, I will not be paid by the professor.

So is it worthwhile to work for free, when I don't like the work just so that I will get a letter of recommendation. How much of an impact will the letter generate in my graduate school application?

Comment: This question is all over the place, please edit it to make it a little easier to follow. Also did you sneak in that to continue working for this professor, you have to quit college? Because no letter of recommendation can make up for not receiving a degree, especially if you're looking at grad school.

Comment: This (after cleaning up) seems like it would be more appropriate on academia rather than here.  In normal industry, working for someone without getting paid would be a no go-- the company wouldn't let someone go from paid employee to unpaid volunteer that still worked there because that would introduce a whole host of liability issues.

Comment: @InBedded16 I am not studying, i am working as a research fellow in the college under the professor. I will edit the question to be more clear.

Comment: @AjaxBanu the question makes much more sense now, thank you. If you have a health condition that requires/is greatly helped by remote work, have you looked into local laws to see if the college being unwilling to let you work remote could be considered discrimination?

Comment: How much do you need that letter? How are your grades and skill mix?

Comment: To the close-voters... "advice on a specific choice", really? My guess is that you voted to close solely on the title of the question (which does say "should I") and didn't read the post before voting. Please, read the post before voting, and you will see that there is an answerable, on-topic question there... (I will try to edit the title to avoid further users from voting based solely on the title).

Comment: Do not work for free! Especially at a job you don't like! This question is a no-brainer. "Now I want to work remotely because of my health condition and the college is not okay with it." Can your work at the College be actually done remotely? Depending on the jurisdiction you're in, your health condition, and the type of accommodation you require, you may be able to force their hand. May be investigate that avenue first.

Comment: I'm not convinced 'is it worthwhile " is answerable since that depends on personal weighting of multiple factors. "What are the tradeoffs" might be, but the question itself implies the big ones. "How much does a reference letter matter, and what kind/from who" would seem more in scope. I think there's an answerable question here, but I'm not sure we have reached it even with the edits; I think we're still in either personal or opinions m spaces as of this moment.

Comment: As written it's quite close to "should I retain a job I don't like just because I want the money." The expected "payment" is in kind/reputation rather than cash, but it's payment. Whether it's enough to continue a job you don't like depends on how much you need that reward, and whether you can still get the reward if you leave now (which might be possible if you've been there a while; ask the prof.)

Comment: Are you kidding me right now?!? Tell them to quit hogging all the slaves and calling it the opportunity of a (their) lifetime! People don't work for free.  You should laugh directly in their faces  to really drive home the point. Sometimes people don't even realize how absurd they're being until you do this. 

Comment: @keshlam, I have good grades. I can get good LORs from my college professors and my managers or directors in my previous companies. But i wanted to gain some research experience and have a letter that shows i am capable of research, since this professor has PhD from a reputable institute it will add value to my resume. 
Like you said he might give even now, but i doubt it. i will try asking. Thanks

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, InBedded16 Thanks i will look into local laws. but i feel like that might take time.

Comment: Well, only you can estimate how strong a recommendation he will give you, how strong his reputation is and how much weight the recommendation will carry, and how much the jobs you are looking for will value that additional information. If I was looking to hire a real research type, I would want to see creative questioning, experiment design and analysis, and other things that an internship usually doesn't demonstrate, especially one where you aren't enjoying it enough to throw yourself into the work and excel. But I'm not in your field, and I'm an engineer , not a scientist.

Comment: And if you aren't enjoying being a research assistant now, do you _want_ a recommendation for a job as a research assistant?

Answer (score 2):

> So is it worthwhile to work for free [...]

It seldom (almost never) is worthwhile to work for free.

> [...] when I do not like the work just so that I will get a letter of recommendation.

Even less worthwhile if you don't like it.

Besides, based on your description it seems that you are not actually learning much from working with the professor.

You also describe that the product/software (from which a paper will be published you say) is not quite good and the work done on it are "hacks" to improve accuracy score (basically to make it look better on the paper I guess, which IMHO is not so honest and suggests that the relevance/impact of the software in reality is not good).

Unless this person is a guru or tremendously wise and valued on the field, I am sure that you can get a letter from someone/somewhere else, one that does not involve sacrificing so much (health, income, career development, learning...).

Comment: He has a PhD from a good institute, which i thought might have good value. But yeah i guess i can try other opportunities. Thank you for your answer.